# contentful & javascript: get only entries with fields.date in the future

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, date, contentful

I'm using contentful as backend for my mobile app.

match fixtures are stored within contentful.
I want to query the next match, but i get the following error:

```
422 (Unprocessable Entity)
```

My function to retrieve the next match:

```
function nextOpponent(){
        var content_Type = mainConfig.config.contentType.match // Matches
        var order = "fields.datum";
        var gt = new Date().toLocaleString();
        console.log(gt);
        var query = "content_type=" + content_Type +
            "&order=" + order +
            "&fields.datum%5Bgte%5D=" + encodeURI(gt);

        contentful.entries(query).then(
            //success
            function(response){
                $scope.nextMatch = response.data.items[0];
                console.log($scope.nextMatch);
            },
            //error
            function(response){

            }
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you are facing is mostly because of the date string being malformed. Date strings have to follow the [ISO-8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). You can create such a formatted string by using the build-in JS function [Date#toISOString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) or via your date formatting library of choice. Besides that you can just pass the arguments as an object.

The following code uses the build-in date method:

```
var gt = new Date().toISOString();

contentful.entries({
  content_type: content_Type,
  order: order,
  'fields.datum[gte]': gt
}).then(function () {
  // go ahead here...
});
```

Additional note:
Contentful will cache the result of queries based on the requested URLs. So if you don't need a high precision, I would suggest using timestamps which only reflects the current date or the respective hour of the day. E.g. `2015-07-28` or `2015-07-28T15:00`

Comment: when I pass the arguments as object, the filters are not being applied anymore. Do you have any idea what could be the reason for that?

Comment: passing the string still works 'contentful.entries(
                "content_type=" + mainConfig.config.contentType.match +
                "&order=" + order +
                "&fields.datum[gte]=" + gt
            ).then(
                //success'

Comment: Hm. Which version are you using? Also what is the value of `mainConfig.config.contentType.match`?

Comment: the value is correct (it works if I place it in a query string). i'm using angular-contentful 1.1.0

Comment: nevermind, it works as string and your solution helped me a lot. Thanks man!

Comment: Oh ok. I thought you were using the official `contentful.js` project. `angular-contentful` seems to need a string instead of on object, though :)